# Successful Installation but when restarting boot order not found, HP Elite 1040 G1

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 19.04, 19.10

It wastes time at boot screen and always creates a new location for boot and i have to wait for sometime and i can not even choose to go to windows either.
I had 18.04 running just fine and it runs fine when again install too but as soon as i try 19.04/19.10 this happens

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your Ubuntu with Livecd and Download boot-repair. It can fix your problem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt -y install boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Comment: tried it many times, didn't work